# Laravel Validation: Get count of existing rows to prevent deletion if last row

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

During the Validation step, I need to prevent the user from deleting last row in a pivot table. Put another way, a user must always have at least one entry in the pivot table.

So when a user requests to `$user->pivot->detach($ids)` I want to somehow check the row count in the pivot table for the user and throw a validation error if the count is 1 or less.

I know I can extend Validator and make a custom rule, but hoping someone knows a built-in way, or has a custom method written already.

Note: the `exists:pivot_user` validation method returns boolean, so it won't work.

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood your question when I posted the answer :)

Comment: So basically the validation rule should check if the number of entries matched in the pivot table for the given `user_id` is greater than `count($ids)` by at least 1? (which would mean that there will be at least one more entry left in the pivot table after `detach` is executed).

Comment: I don't think there is a 'built-in' way to do this. You have to write it yourself. I'd put the `$user->pivot()->detach($ids)` in a transaction and rollback if `$user->pivot()->count() < 1`. Does that work?

Comment: @edpaez, yeah that is an option. However, I use the Command Pattern and separation of concerns dictates the check for row count should be in the Validator, not in the Handler. I'll probably write a custom validation method that does the check. Thank you for your idea, I do like the db transactions approach.